# Web development with IIS security

Tags: iis

I've been working on an old secure website on my local machine's IIS on occasion.  It's probably been a couple weeks since the last time.  However, now all of a sudden IIS seems to have a problem with it.  I can't even get to the root page.  Chrome reports a general failure.  Edge is more informative with:

> This might be because the site uses outdated or unsafe TLS security settings. If this keeps happening, try contacting the website’s owner.

Well, I'm the website owner and I have no clue what might have happened.  It works fine in production, but the local development version suddenly just doesn't work.  So far I haven't found anything useful on Google.  Is there a common checklist for troubleshooting these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Security certificate under bindings was set to "Development" originally, but that vanished.  Reset it and good to go again!

Comment: As VS installer can upgrade IIS Express (and its certificate) silently, this kind of issues can be expected. Good that you found the solution.

Comment: Ahhh, yes, I did get a large VS update the other day.  I never thought about that impacting IIS!